# Using formal power series to solve nasty equations

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, approximation

Consider a function $f:[0,\infty)\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, and suppose that given some $a>0$, I would like to solve for $x\in\mathbb R$ satisfying
\begin{align}
  f(\delta, x) = a.
\end{align}
Suppose, additionally, that $f$ is sufficiently horrible, that obtaining a solution in closed form is difficult or impossible, but that I only care about finding solutions for "small" delta.

My first instinct in finding such solutions would be to perform a formal power series expansion of $x$ in the parameter $\delta$,
\begin{align}
  x = x_0 +x_1\delta + x_2\delta^2\cdots 
\end{align}
plug this into the function $f$, expand the result as a formal power power series in $\delta$ as well (if this turns out to be possible);
\begin{align}
  f(\delta, x_0+x_1\delta+x_2\delta^2+\cdots) = f_0 + f_1\delta + f_2\delta^2+\cdots
\end{align}
then set the right hand side equal to $a$, and obtain the following sequence of equations to determine the coefficients $x_k$ order-by-order in $\delta$:
\begin{align}
  f_0 &= a \\
  f_1 &= 0 \\
  f_2 &= 0 \\
  &\vdots
\end{align}
Is there a sense in which such manipulations with formal power series can lead to approximate solutions to the original equation?  In particular, if the resulting power series for $x$ seems to have a nonzero radius of convergence in $\delta$ about $\delta = 0$, then have I obtained an approximation to a solution to the original equation?

Something similar to this has come up in a theoretical physics research problem, and this is all very mirky water for me, so any insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this related to perturbation theory? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory

Comment: @DanielR I think it's safe to say that this is a question about a specific example of perturbation theory.